# Is it possible to wrap an unordered list in CSS to account for different size list items

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to represent an unordered list so that it is displayed horizontally and adjusts for different list items height. I tried using 'columns' but it displays the list item sequentially starting in the first column.

How can I represent the following list in the format shown in the diagram below:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

I want to avoid using any third-party libraries. Is it possible to achieve this with CSS (or CSS3) and HTML?

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    padding-right: 20px;
      list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1<img  height="30px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
    <li>2<img  height="60px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
        <li>3<img  height="40px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
        <li>4<img  height="80px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
        <li>5<img  height="30px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
        <li>6<img  height="30px;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Wiki-commons.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you keep undoing my edits that embed your image in your post? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you share your CSS code please?

Comment: what I have for the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/9qa8wexx/5

Comment: You could use float + nth-child, but as it stands [this question is off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @zzzzBov - that won't work either. "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document." JavaScript would be required like with masonry.

Comment: @j08691, oh right, flexbox then.

Comment: @zzzBov I don't see how flexbox would do this, but I haven't used them much. Care to explain?

Comment: Here's the code that I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/1n706w5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple, two column only method

https://jsfiddle.net/aypLvoag/4/

CSS doesn't consider height when elements are floated, so you'll need to do some JavaScript to keep track of the current height reached within each column. If you only have two columns, you can float elements to the left or to the right, which makes things easier.

```
var floatLists = document.getElementsByClassName("floatList");
for(var i=0; i < floatLists.length; ++i) {
    var leftHeight = 0;
    var rightHeight = 0;
    var items = floatLists[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    for(var j=0; j < items.length; ++j) {
        if(leftHeight <= rightHeight) {
            items[j].style.cssFloat = "left";
            leftHeight += items[j].offsetHeight;
        } else {
            items[j].style.cssFloat = "right";
            rightHeight += items[j].offsetHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

## Any amount of columns method

https://jsfiddle.net/tr12j5xx/6/
(updated again, showed it works with thick borders and uses random number of columns for demo)

Finally, this method requires a lot more manual placement, but it's nice nonetheless.

First of all, I made some helper methods for getting and setting the size of elements because without jquery which does it all for us, it can be confusing to remember what is what, especially when some values are strings with px at the end. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Y32/25/) I found the other day for more info.

```
// get the available width inside an element - can convert % width in pixels!
function getInnerWidth(elem) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    return elem.offsetWidth - parseFloat(style.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(style.paddingRight) - parseFloat(style.borderLeftWidth) - parseFloat(style.borderRightWidth);
}

// get the total width of borders, padding and margin - basically anything but the inner width
function getAirWidth(elem) {
    return elem.offsetWidth - getInnerWidth(elem);
}

// set the total width of an element (including padding, border and margin)
function setTotalWidth(elem, width) {
  elem.style.width = (width - getAirWidth(elem)) + "px";
}
```

Alright, now the column generation. Instead of floating elements, we have to manually place them. If you set an element's position style to "absolute" or "relative", any child element whose position is set to "absolute" will actually be relative to that parent. So if we set the list to "absolute" or "relative" and then the items to "absolute", we can set each item's top-left position based on the top-left corner of the list.

I used the same structure as before where we keep track of the height of each column - this time we'll need an array though. As we loop through the elements of the list, we always ad the element to the smallest column. The `apply` function allows us to pass the content of an array as parameters to a function. You can call `.apply` on any function if you didn't know. Here, I'm using it to get the size of the smallest column. Then we can use indexof to find it. If more than one column has the same size, indexof will return the leftmost one.

```
// split a list into columns (fixed size)
function splitColumnsFixed(list, nbColumns, itemName) {
    list.style.position = "relative";
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName(itemName || "li");
    var width = getInnerWidth(list) / nbColumns;
    
    var colHeight = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nbColumns; ++i) colHeight[i] = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var col = colHeight.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, colHeight));
        items[i].style.position = "absolute";
        items[i].style.left = width * col + "px";
        items[i].style.top = colHeight[col] + "px";
        setTotalWidth(items[i], width);
        colHeight[col] += items[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    
    list.style.height = Math.max.apply(Math, colHeight) + "px";
}
```

Note that this code will only work if the list has a set width before the code is called, because I'm dividing this width across the elements. JSFiddle's default CSS sets the body's content to 100% width by default. Also, the last line sets the height of the list so it matches the longest column. Since we set the position of all items to "absolute", the list element will behave as if it was empty, so it will have a height of 0px if we don't do that - meaning the remainder of the page will be placed as if the list wasn't there! By setting the height of the list, we prevent that from happening.

This code is nice on its own, but when we resize the page, the items don't get resized. While the list has a % based width, we placed the elements manually in pixels. That won't do. Luckily, CSS3 comes to the rescue with the `calc` function, which allows you to perform arithmetic operations on both percentages and pixels in CSS. Just remember that you need to put a space around operators (+ - * /). In other words, you can set an item's width to `calc(100% - 10px)` in CSS. With this information, I made another version of the function. This time, all values are set in percentage.

```
// split a list into columns (scalable size)
function splitColumnsPercent(list, nbColumns, itemName) {
    list.style.position = "relative";
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName(itemName || "li");
    
    var colHeight = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nbColumns; ++i) colHeight[i] = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var col = colHeight.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, colHeight));
        items[i].style.position = "absolute";
        items[i].style.left = (100 * col / nbColumns) + "%";
        items[i].style.top = colHeight[col] + "px";
        items[i].style.width = "calc(100% / " + nbColumns + " - " + getAirWidth(items[i]) + "px)";
        colHeight[col] += items[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    
    list.style.height = Math.max.apply(Math, colHeight) + "px";
}
```

---

## Failed attempts

We tried to do that without JS by using the nth-child selector, as pointed in the comments by Gael. [See on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aypLvoag/2)

```
li:nth-child(odd){ float:left;}
li:nth-child(even){ float:right;}
```

While this works fine when the variation in height is small, you'll see it break when one column gets much bigger than the other. Also, this only alternates placing elements to the left and right, but it doesn't keep track of heights to distribute them in a logical order - which is why JavaScript is needed.

If you can split elements in multiple lists yourself, it's much easier, but the asker wanted to divide a single ul in two columns. Still, here's what you would do in that case.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLrz58yk/1/

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li style="height: 30px">1</li>
        <li style="height: 60px">2</li>
        <li style="height: 40px">3</li>
        <li style="height: 50px">4</li>
        <li style="height: 35px">5</li>
        <li style="height: 30px">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li style="height: 40px">1</li>
        <li style="height: 30px">2</li>
        <li style="height: 40px">3</li>
        <li style="height: 35px">4</li>
        <li style="height: 70px">5</li>
        <li style="height: 30px">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li style="height: 30px">1</li>
        <li style="height: 60px">2</li>
        <li style="height: 40px">3</li>
        <li style="height: 50px">4</li>
        <li style="height: 35px">5</li>
        <li style="height: 30px">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
ul{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}

li {
    background-color: #5555FF;
    color: white;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

(I hereby release my code in the public domain.)

Comment: Thanks! Code looks good but it assumes only 2 columns. It's possible to have n number of columns. But I think given the question asked, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Gael I was trying to do that and for some reason couldn't get it to work, this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Grouping by column won't work for me because it's a dynamic list and I cannot know the number of 'LI's or the height of each

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I've changed the height a bit and noticed that it doesn't act correctly. See https://jsfiddle.net/aypLvoag/3/ and look at box 6 which should be displayed on the left side.

Comment: After further investigation, I don't think this approach works because if the height of a column is larger then then heigh of the next 2 columns then the code breaks and shows right floating element on the left and right floating on the right.

Comment: Yeah, I should have tested with randomized heights instead of typing values. I actually realized this and opened SE to write it here only to land on your comment. I'll try to do this in JS as I might need this one day, be back soon :)

Comment: There, I'm done with editing (hopefully) so you shouldn't get 100 notifications. That was a nice challenge :)

Comment: Thanks @JacqueGoupil - great job - You should release it on GitHub and start a new framework.

Answer (score -1):

You could use css columns, but it is not respecting your order: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9qa8wexx/10/

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
}
```

Then, you can edit the order of the li's with some js:
http://jsfiddle.net/9qa8wexx/11/

```
var odd_lis= document.querySelectorAll("li:nth-child(even)");

var ul= odd_lis[0].parentNode;
for( var i= 0; i< odd_lis.length; i++){
    ul.removeChild(odd_lis[i]);
    ul.appendChild(odd_lis[i]);
}
```

But I would advice you to use the [isotope library](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaOvjr